# Is there any way to read row and make it unreadable

Tags: postgresql, concurrency

I have table with below schema.

```
CREATE TABLE public.crewcode (
crewcodeid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('crewcode_crewcodeid_seq'::regclass),
nationality character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
code character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
codenumber bigint,
isediting boolean,
CONSTRAINT crewcode_pkey PRIMARY KEY (crewcodeid))
```

Insert some data

```
INSERT INTO public.crewcode(
crewcodeid, nationality, code, codenumber, isediting)
VALUES ('IN', '000001', 1, false);
```

I have one procedure below that i run from ado.net and get some result.

when i run this procedure it will get single record nationality wise in desc manner. then fetch codenumber from it and increment it by 1 and then adds one row with that incremented number. you can see code in below stored procedure.

```
DECLARE
    LastCodeNumber integer;
    codeId integer;
    editCheck boolean;
    NewCodeNumber integer;
begin 

SELECT crewcodeid, codenumber, isediting FROM public.crewcode where nationality=NationalityInput order by codenumber desc limit 1
INTO codeId, LastCodeNumber, editCheck;

if (codeId is NULL) then
    INSERT INTO public.crewcode (nationality, code, codenumber, isediting) VALUES(NationalityInput, '000001', 1, false);
    crewCode = '000001';
else
    if not (editCheck) then
    
        UPDATE public.crewcode set isediting=true where crewcodeid=codeId;
        
    else
        return;
    END if;
        
    
    NewCodeNumber = LastCodeNumber + 1;
    crewCode = LPAD(NewCodeNumber::text, 6, '0');
    
    
    INSERT INTO public.crewcode (nationality, code, codenumber, isediting) VALUES(NationalityInput, crewCode, NewCodeNumber, false);


    UPDATE public.crewcode set isediting=false where crewcodeid=codeId;
END if;

end;
```

Now problem is that when I call stored procedure parallel then i will create result like below SS.

[this should not happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6wL3.png)

What should i do that there won't be any duplicate like above SS? I have tried with adding IsEditing column and make it true, false when reading but that's not working because in parallel code everything will execute at same time so my solution won't work. is there any other way to do this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Create  a unique constraint to prevent duplicates

Comment: can't do that code will be unique nationality wise.

Comment: It seems you want a unique index on `(nationality, code, codenumber)`

Comment: I have added unique index on table and it is working fine. Thanks for solution. but when i make 10 parallel code in some cases it will give me ' duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ind_crewcode' error. So is there any way? that my SP should wait till other execution finish so it won't generate above error.